# Use Dictionary as an argument in a sub or function

Tags: wpf, vb.net, arguments

I am having a bit of an issue using Dictionary as an argument in a sub or function

```vb
' Dictionary
Sub DoSomethingWithDictionary(ByVal MyDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, String))
    ' Some Code
End Sub

' Some Sub that calls sub with Dictionary
Sub SomeSub()
    ' I get a warning on the line below:
    DoSomethingWithDictionary(New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {"TheValue", "TheKey"})
End Sub
```

I get the following Error:

> Argument not specified for parameter 'value' of 'Public Overload Sub
>   Add(Key as String, Value as String)

Comment: You need one set of braces for the list and then one set of braces for each item.

Comment: Can you please set the value of the dictionary outside the function args ()

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers. I would never have figured it out without the help.